# Is it possible to initialize a ConfigurationSection from an external file?

Tags: c#, .net, config

I have a custom configuration property in my app.  It looks something like this:

```
public class OverrideConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty(PROP_ADMIN_CONNSTR)]
    public StringConfigurationElement AdminConnectionString
    {
        get { return base[PROP_ADMIN_CONNSTR] as StringConfigurationElement; }
        set { base[PROP_ADMIN_CONNSTR] = value; }
    }

    // .. Various other properties, but you get the idea
}
```

However, what I'd like is to allow the .config file to be pointed to an external file source.  Something like this:

```
<ServiceOverrides file="Overrides.local.config" />
```

Now, the built-in `configSource` attribute is *close* to what I need, but it has two major issues.

1. Files *must* exist.  If the file doesn't exist, it errors out.
2. Files must be in the current directory or in a *deeper* directory.  In other words, I can't point to `..\Overrides.local.config`

What I want is pretty much identical to the `<appSettings file="..." />` configuration element.  However, that attribute seems to be something `appSettings` implemented, and is not part of the base `ConfigurationSection` class.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to override something in `ConfigurationSection` that will basically read XML data from a different location?  I don't want to change any other aspect of my class or do my own XML deserialization or anything.  I simply want to check if a file exists, if so, load in the XML contents from *that* file, otherwise load in the default XML contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have a working solution.  I'm not sure if it's the *best* approach, but it does appear to work exactly how I want.

```
private readonly Queue<String> externalSources = new Queue<String>();

protected override void DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, bool serializeCollectionKey)
{
    var externalFile = reader.GetAttribute("File");
    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(externalFile))
    {
        externalSources.Enqueue(externalFile);
    }

    base.DeserializeElement(reader, serializeCollectionKey);
}

protected override void PostDeserialize()
{
    base.PostDeserialize();

    // Override data with local stuff
    if (externalSources.Count == 0) return;

    string file = externalSources.Dequeue();
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
    {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create(file);
        base.DeserializeSection(reader);
    }
}
```

First, I trap the `DeserializeElement` event, which happens when we read the `<ServiceOverrides>` element.  We check if it has a `File` attribute, and if so we add it to a queue of external sources to load.

Next, we trap the `PostDeserialize` event, which gets called after all the local XML is parsed.  If there's an external source in the queue, we dequeue it, check if it actually exists, then create an `XmlReader` with the contents of that file.  Now we can simply call `DeserializeSection` *again* and pass in our new reader.  The `ConfigurationSection` class is smart enough to just *overwrite* or *append* any new data to the existing configuration.  What I get at the end is an aggregation of both configuration files, where the include file wins in the event of a duplicate.

Now, what's this nonsense with the queue?  Well, it seems every time you call `DeserializeSection`, it'll call `PostDeserialize` again.  So, if we simply trapped `PostDeserialize`, check the `File` attribute, and call `DeserializeSection` again, we'd get in an infinite loop.  We could just use a *flag* to remember if we already loaded the external file, but a queue has the added benefit of allowing the include file to load more include files (not that *I'd* ever want to do that, but you might).

**Tips:** This will probably work fairly well, and is simple to understand, but if you're using it in production code, there's a few things you could improve on.  First, `externalSources` doesn't *really* need to be a queue, since these calls aren't actually recursive.  You can probably just use a `string`, and set it to null after you're done processing that file.  Second, this could cause an infinite loop in the event of a circular include chain.  You could create a `List<T>` of previously included files, then check if the include already exists in that list before adding it to the queue.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I was running into this exact problem at work today. Thanks for the solution!